# GeoServer installation issue on Windows 10

Tags: geoserver, installation

I installed GeoServer 2.13.4 with JRE 1.8.0_241 on Windows 10 64-bit system. The installation was fine however, when I goto http://localhost:8080/geoserver from the browser there is an error 404. I am not sure what the problem is followed the installation steps in documentation for the respective version. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: How did you install GeoServer and how do you know that the installation was fine?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Why not use a current version of GeoServer? what does the log file say when you start GeoServer up?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 8080 port is correct, this means that the page is not.

1. I would suggest you restart your machine to make sure all the services have started
2. Please try the following link: http://localhost:8080/Geoserver/Web/

I hope this helps.